# sproc execution far slower than SQL ad-hoc query equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a sproc that was taking far more time than I expected.

I pulled out the SQL and ran it with just DECLARED variables for the parameters.  It ran nearly instantaneously (versus a reliable 8 seconds with the sproc).  This is the same SQL on same machine, returning the same data.

How can I figure out and fix what is causing the sproc to be slow?

This is on SQL Server Express.

Thanks much.

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing: http://omnibuzz-sql.blogspot.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is parameter sniffing. Just change your procedure to do the same thing: copy all of you parameters into local variables and than have the body of your procedure use the loal variables instead.

Comment: Thanks RBarryYoung and rexem!  Making this change made the sproc perform as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of the stored procedure, check for `ANSI_NULLS`.  Make sure that this is turned on. (`SET ANSI_NULLS ON`)

By default in the Query Window in SSMS it is turned on.  We found a problem where `ANSI_NULLS` was explicitly set to off and it drastically slowed down the sproc.

Comment: IIRC this comes from indexes that the sproc wants to use being built with a different setting (and thus incompatible)

Comment: SETing certain options (including ANSI_NULLS) within a stored proc can cause SP recompilations - most certainly the cause of your performance issues. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243586 for more info

Answer (score 0):

Is an app running the stored procedure, or are you running the stored procedure via Query Analyzer?